# Where is the best place to show the splash screen using prism 7

Tags: wpf, prism, splash-screen

I'm new to wpf and prism. I've created a splash window containing a progressbar which it's value is going from 0 to 100 in a backgroundworker.
I don't know where exactly to show the splash screen and close it.

I tried to show the splash before resolving the shell, but it ends up with having splash and shell open together and don't know where to close the splash either.

```
protected override Window CreateShell()
{
    Views.SplashScreen splashScreen = new Views.SplashScreen();
    splashScreen.Show();

    return Container.Resolve<Shell>();
}
```

thank you.

Comment: This is for the (old) bootstrapper, but it's still there in Prism 7 and you can use `PrismApplicationBase.InitializeModules` the same way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40596743/prism-module-loading-locks-up-dispatcher-thread-is-there-a-way-around-this/40608713#40608713

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As written [somewhere else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40596743/prism-module-loading-locks-up-dispatcher-thread-is-there-a-way-around-this/40608713#40608713), `InitializeModules` is a good way to handle the splash screen:

```
internal class App : PrismApplication
{
    // [...]
    protected override void InitializeModules()
    {
        var splashScreen = new SplashScreen( "myLogo.png" );
        splashScreen.Show( false );
        try
        {
            base.InitializeModules();
        }
        finally
        {
            splashScreen.Close( TimeSpan.Zero );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this solution works fine, unless I want my splash screen do some fake load progress(it does actually) but here `try` block happens in less than a second and `finally` closes the splash before its progress complete. another problem is that I have no argument in `show` and `close` of a window and have no idea what are they for.

Comment: Have a look at the `SplashScreen` class for the parameters, but you can roll your own, the framework-provided one is just a suggestion. If you really have to slow down your app's initialization, you can add anything you like in your modules' initialization or directly into the try-block.